# How can I arrange the project successfully?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIAlk.png)
The error occured during I arranged the project to android emulator.I use Xamarin to develop android application.

I used to uninstall the android sdk,but it doesn't work.I hope that I can arrange the project successfully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

About Xamarin.Android error: `JAVAC0000`, you can refer to the official solution:

> If you have Java source code in your project with a build action of `AndroidJavaSource`, verify your Java syntax is correct.
>
> Consider submitting a [bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Submitting-Bugs,-Feature-Requests,-and-Pull-Requests) if you are getting this error under normal circumstances.

For more info you can see this: [Xamarin.Android error JAVAC0000](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/messages/javac0000.md).